# sending a png from c++ server to java client

Tags: java, android, c++

I'm trying to send a png image from a c++ server to a Java (android studio) client (the image is saved on the server). I read that I need to encode the image in base64, send it, decode it, convert it to a byte array and then to bitmap. (I should probably mention at this point that I'm not that familiar with android studio). To be honest, I don't even know if I need to do all that, that's just what I found on the internet...

Anyway, so I started doing that and here's what I've got:
(This is the c++ server part, Message is a class I made and it handles part of the socketing-magic. Also, I should mention most of these functions were not made by me. And don't worry about the way the protocol looks like in sendImage, I just added it so that you can see how the image is sent. I'm using https://github.com/tkislan/base64 for the base64 encoding)

```
void MessageHandler::handleSendPicture(Message & msg)
{
    SOCKET& socket = msg.getSocket();
    char* image;
    std::ifstream f;     
    f.open("C:\\images\\A.png", ios::binary);


    if (f.is_open())
    {
        f.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        unsigned int length = f.tellg();
        f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        image = new char[length];
        f.read(image, length);

        f.close();
    }

    else
    {
        image = (char*)"Empty";
    }

    Message to_client = Message(msg.getSocket(), SEND_PIC, image);
    to_client.sendImage();
}


void Message::sendImage(unsigned int size, char* image)
{
    string prefix = "04" + getPaddedNumber(size, 5);
    string message = prefix;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        message += image[i];
    }

    const char* data = message.c_str();
    cout << "message size: " << message.size() << endl;
    if (send(this->_socket, data, message.size(), 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        throw std::exception("Error while sending message to client");
    }
}
```

And on the (Java) application side: (Don't worry about startOperation, it just handles the networking magic, also, client._fromServer.firstElement() is the image string sent from the server)

```
case R.id.translate_word:
                if (startOperation("SendPicture"))
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(client._fromServer.firstElement());
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sign);

                    image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
                    client._success = false;
                }
```

The server crashes when the client asks for the picture, and it does on the Base64::Encode line. I don't really know how that works either and I'm sorry for being a noob overall :P
So, I wanted to ask if all this is even needed? is there an easier way of doing this? am I even doing this right? could it be the base64 converter? Thanks a lot in advance <3 Much love :)

Edit: initialized the new_message string, now the server doesn't crash but nothing happens on the client side... it does get a response but nothing happens

Edit2: I managed to send the message from the server properly (or at least I think so), the problem was the 0's in the binary file were read as null terminators. anyway, when I receive the message in the client only 28642 bytes are received (out of 30965). Does anyone know what's wrong? (also I gave up on the base64 encoding for now). Updated the sendImage code above. Rest are unchanged.

Comment: "*The server crashes when the client asks for the picture, and it does on the Base64::Encode line.*" - Any error message? Maybe a seqfault?

Comment: Looking at [`simpe_test.cc`](https://github.com/tkislan/base64/blob/master/base64.h), it looks like `Base64::Encode(const std::string &, std::string *)` expects an already initialized `std::string` as second argument. But this is more a guess than hard knowledge.

Comment: thanks, i initialized the string and now it doesn't crash, still doesn't work though :\ nothing happens on the client side now